# Toggled menu in WordPress Underscores makes a jump

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a toggle menu for my site, but when I open the menu everything jumps some pixels to the left. I have played with some settings, but nothing worked. I made some small changes to the original CSS for the navigation, to make the button and the ul to align. The menu should be opening the list straight down, not affecting the button's and menu's position.

Is there a better way to set up the js function or can it be fixed in CSS? I used the built-in navigation function from WordPress starter theme Underscores.

```js
( function() {
 const siteNavigation = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );

 // Return early if the navigation don't exist.
 if ( ! siteNavigation ) {
  return;
 }

 const button = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[ 0 ];

 // Return early if the button don't exist.
 if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
  return;
 }

 const menu = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[ 0 ];

 // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
 if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
  button.style.display = 'none';
  return;
 }

 if ( ! menu.classList.contains( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
  menu.classList.add( 'nav-menu' );
 }

 // Toggle the .toggled class and the aria-expanded value each time the button is clicked.
 button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  siteNavigation.classList.toggle( 'toggled' );

  if ( button.getAttribute( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'true' ) {
   button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
  } else {
   button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
  }
 } );

 // Remove the .toggled class and set aria-expanded to false when the user clicks outside the navigation.
 document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  const isClickInside = siteNavigation.contains( event.target );

  if ( ! isClickInside ) {
   siteNavigation.classList.remove( 'toggled' );
   button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
  }
 } );

 // Get all the link elements within the menu.
 const links = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

 // Get all the link elements with children within the menu.
 const linksWithChildren = menu.querySelectorAll( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' );

 // Toggle focus each time a menu link is focused or blurred.
 for ( const link of links ) {
  link.addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
  link.addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
 }

 // Toggle focus each time a menu link with children receive a touch event.
 for ( const link of linksWithChildren ) {
  link.addEventListener( 'touchstart', toggleFocus, false );
 }

 /**
  * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
  */
 function toggleFocus() {
  if ( event.type === 'focus' || event.type === 'blur' ) {
   let self = this;
   // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
   while ( ! self.classList.contains( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
    // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
    if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
     self.classList.toggle( 'focus' );
    }
    self = self.parentNode;
   }
  }

  if ( event.type === 'touchstart' ) {
   const menuItem = this.parentNode;
   event.preventDefault();
   for ( const link of menuItem.parentNode.children ) {
    if ( menuItem !== link ) {
     link.classList.remove( 'focus' );
    }
   }
   menuItem.classList.toggle( 'focus' );
  }
 }
}() );
```

```css
.main-navigation {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 text-align: right;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
 left: auto;
}

.main-navigation li {
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 left: -40px;
}

.main-navigation a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
 display: block;
}
.main-navigation.toggled{
 height: 170px;
}



/* CUSTOM HEADER STYLES */

.site-header {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 30px;
 padding: 50px 0;
}

.site-branding p {
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0;
}
.site-branding p a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Navigation */

nav.main-navigation {
 width: auto;
 float: right;
```

```html
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  
  <div class="site-branding">

   <?php
   the_custom_logo();
   if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
    ?>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php
   else :
    ?>
    <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php
   endif; ?>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
   <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( '&#9776;', 'ab-portfolio' ); ?></button>
   <?php
   wp_nav_menu(
    array(
     'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
     'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
    )
   );
   ?>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

 </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

[Closed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CGbK.png)
[Open menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdTjH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the content of your `<ul>` is bigger than the button itself and it always tries to align on the left.

You can simply fix it adding a `float: right;` to the button.

```css
.menu-toggle {
   float: right;
}
```

Alternatively you can try add some `margin-left` and `margin-right` to the button, like this:

```css
.menu-toggle {
   margin: 0 8px;
}
```

In this last case you can skip the `float: right;`.

Here's a working Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/QWyKZLX

Hope this helps!